# Naive Divide-and-Conquer Approach to Polynomial Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, recursion, language-agnostic, divide-and-conquer

Given two polynomials A(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + a<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + ... + a<sub>n-1</sub>x<sup>n-1</sup>, and B(x), defined similarly with coefficients b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub> ... b<sub>n-1</sub>, we seek A(x) * B(x).

I'm examining a simple divide and conquer algorithm as a preface to learning Karatsuba's algorithm, and I understand the basic principle, namely:

Defining A(x) = M<sub>0</sub>(x) + M<sub>1</sub>(x)x<sup>n/2</sup>, where M<sub>1</sub>(x) = a<sub>n-1</sub>x<sup>n/2-1</sup> + a<sub>n-2</sub>x<sup>n/2-2</sup> + ... + a<sub>n/2</sub> (i.e. upper half coefficients) and M<sub>0</sub>(x) = a<sub>n/2-1</sub>x<sup>n/2-1</sup> + a<sub>n/2-2</sub>x<sup>n/2-2</sup> + ... + a<sub>0</sub> (i.e. lower half coefficients), and B(x) = N<sub>0</sub>(x) + N<sub>1</sub>(x)x<sup>n/2</sup>, with N<sub>0</sub>(x) and N<sub>1</sub>(x) defined in a similar fashion to M<sub>0</sub>(x) and M<sub>1</sub>(x), respectively. Then we can rewrite A(x) * B(x) as (M<sub>1</sub>N<sub>1</sub>)x<sup>n</sup> + (M<sub>1</sub>N<sub>0</sub> + M<sub>0</sub>N<sub>1</sub>)x<sup>n/2</sup> + M<sub>0</sub>N<sub>0</sub>.

However, I'm have a little trouble understanding the "conquer" step in the pseudocode provided:

```
Function PolyMult(A, B, n, a, b)
    R = array[0 ... 2n - 1];
    if n = 1:
        R[0] = A[a] * B[b]; return R;
    R[0 ... n - 2] = PolyMult(A, B, n/2, a, b);
    R[n ... 2n - 2] = PolyMult(A, B, n/2, a + n/2, b + n/2);
    MN = PolyMult(A, B, n/2, a, b + n/2);
    NM = PolyMult(A, B, n/2, a + n/2, b);
    R[n/2 ... n + n /2 - 2] += MN + NM;
    return R;
End Function
```

Specifically, I'm unsure as to why the first n - 1 and last n - 1 terms of the resultant array can be directly initialized, whereas the middle n - 1 terms need to be computed with addition assignment. Could someone elaborate on this aspect of the algorithm?

In general, I believe I am missing some important intuition in regards to recursion or divide and conquer (seemingly both). What are important general paradigms when attempting to implement a recursive divide and conquer solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: what is the (maximum) degree of polynomials M0,M1,N0,N1?

```
n/2-1
```

What is the (maximum) degree of each product M0*N0 M1*N1 M0*N1 m1*N0?

```
n - 2
```

Now the degree of M1*N1*x^n ?

```
2*n - 2
```

And what is the value of coefficients of M1*N1*x^n from degree 0 to n - 2 ?

```
0
```

So do they overlap with the coefficients of M0*N0 ?

```
no
```

Now the last part (M0*N1+M1*N0)*x^(n/2), what is the valuation and degree?

```
n/2 and n/2 + n - 2 respectively
```

Do these overlap partially with M0*N0 and M1*N1*x^n ?

```
yes
```

So you have to use += for the last part